# How to determine all finitely generated subrings of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a homework question in a course in Groups and Rings.

The exercise is to determine finitely generated subrings of $\mathbb Q$, where such subrings are to include $1$. The course is following the book Abstract Algebra; theory and applications by Judson.

I've tried to work straight from the subring theorem; for example, suppose $R$ is smallest subring to include the rational numbers $r_1, r_2$, then it must also include all powers of $r_1$, all powers of $r_2$, all products of these powers, powers of $r_1 - r_2$ etc. This approach quickly gets out of hand and I fail to see a general pattern that would allow me to determine all such finitely generated subrings.

Is there a slick way of approaching the problem?

Comment: Try thinking about denominators

Comment: Let $A_R = \{ p, \exists a/b\in R, \gcd(a,b)=1, p| b\}$, $B_R = \{ p,1/p\in R\}$. Prove that $A_R=B_R$ and $B_R=B_S\iff R=S$.

Comment: @reuns , thank you, I understand the logic of this construction. However, I can't seem to tie the knot and make the inference that given any subring $R$ containing a finite set of rational numbers, the sets $B_R$ help me determine all the finitely generated subrings of $\mathbb Q$. i.e, is it the case that the sets $B_R$ determine the finitely generated subrings?

Comment: $p$ is prime, $A_R=B_R$ is the list of primes inversible in your ring. The finitely generated assumption says it is finite, but you don't need it.

Comment: @reuns , Ah, of course.. $p$ is prime was the missing piece! I think I can write a full solution now, thanks!